# Is it possible to rotate a drawable in the xml description?

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, android-xml

I am creating an app, with resources that can be reused (because buttons are always the same, but mirrored or rotated). I do want to use the same resource so I don't have to add 3 more resources that are exactly like the original but rotated. But I also don't want to mix the code with things that can be declared in the XML or make transformations with a matrix that will cost processing time.

I've got a two state button declared in an XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/and_card_details_button_down_left_onclick" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/and_card_details_button_down_left" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and I want to reuse the drawable because it will be the same but rotated 90º and 45º and I assign to the button as a drawable.

```
<Button android:id="@+id/Details_Buttons_Top_Left_Button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/details_menu_large_button" />
```

I know that I can rotate it with a [`RotateDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RotateDrawable.html) or with a [`Matrix`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) but as I already explained I don't like that approach.

Is it possible to achieve that directly on the XML or what do you think that will be the best way to do it? Put all resources but rotated, rotate them in the code?

--- EDIT ---
The answer of @dmaxi works great, this is how to combine it with an item list :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <rotate 
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:toDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:drawable="@drawable/and_card_details_button_up_onclick"/>
    </item>

    <item>
        <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:toDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:drawable="@drawable/and_card_details_button_up_onclick"/>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: No need to apologize your english is just fine. And welcome to SO!

Comment: look in to the same problem on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727426/andriod-how-to-create-the-stack-kind-of-image-backgrounds any suggestion would be great!

Comment: Vector based drawables greatly simplifies matters (answer below).

Answer (score 147, accepted):

I could [rotate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RotateDrawable.html) in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:toDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:drawable="@drawable/mainmenu_background">
</rotate>
```

The `fromDegrees` is important.

Basically this is a rotate animation defined in XML. With `fromDegrees` you define the initial rotated state. The `toDegrees` is the final rotated state of the drawable in the animation sequence but can be anything if you don't want to use animation.

I don't think it allocates resources for animation as it doesn't have to be loaded as animation. As a drawable it is rendered as it's initial state and should be put in the `drawable` resource folder.
To use it as an animation you should put it in `anim` resource folder and can start the animation like this (just an example):

```
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation);
rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
myView.startAnimation(rotation);
```

Comment: Thanks that's perfect! i combined that with the item and its exactly what i need, i want to post the code, i don't know if its better to edit your answer or my question...
And for mirroring the image do i have to play with pivot x & y?

Comment: Well, I'm happy I could help, edit the answer if you wish. pivotX and pivotY defines the center point of the rotation. For mirroring I don't have idea because this XML can only define 2D rotation.

Comment: @dmaxi This is rotating the drawable via a rotation animation isn't it? Wouldn't that be somewhat inefficient?

Comment: I made this but from 0 to 360 degrees because i want a full rotation, the problem is in small screens it rotates deformed, any clue?

Comment: Why should "fromDegrees" be the same as "toDegrees" ? Why shouldn't it be 0?

Comment: I added explanatory text chaps, I hope it helps.

Comment: There was a bug in Android M affecting this exact rotate drawable, it disappears completely, so if you choose this sollution then it will be broken in M. Was fixed for N.

Comment: @androidguy This should really be added to the answer.

Comment: Unable to rotate svg drawable. Any idea?

Comment: This doesn't work with vector drawables

Answer (score 38):

I could rotate left arrow right in XML as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="180"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:drawable="@drawable/left">
</rotate>
```

Attached image for reference.

[image]

Comment: i am doing this but i can't set the background to layout any idea?

Answer (score 30):

If vector based drawables are used, in conjunction with an **ImageView**, style, and color state list, your button can be refactored as follows:

**Note:** Vector drawables are significantly smaller than images, so extra, explicit definitions don't incur much overhead, and makes for clear, explicit code (although I've read that hand modifying vector assets should be avoided, I'd rather deal with the overhead of updating a couple of files than having transformations on one):

**Note:** Android Studio is a great source for vector assets.

**res\values\styles.xml**

```
<!--ImageView-->
<style name="Details_Buttons_Top_Left_Button">
  <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>    
  <item name="android:tint">@color/button_csl</item>    
</style>
```

**res\color\button_csl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/grey_disabled"/>
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/orange_hilite"/>
  <item android:color="@color/black"/>  
</selector>
```

**details_menu_large_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/and_card_details_button_down_left_onclick" /> <!-- pressed -->
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/and_card_details_button_down_left" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

**Details_Buttons_Top_Left_Button**

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/Details_Buttons_Top_Left_Button"
           style="@style/Details_Buttons_Top_Left_Button"
           android:src="@drawable/details_menu_large_button" />
```

**and_card_details_button_down_left.xml** (ic_play_arrow_black_24dp.xml)

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">  
  <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M8,5v14l11,-7z"/>

</vector>
```

**and_card_details_button_down_left_onclick.xml** (ic_play_arrow_black_24dp.xml modified)

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
  <group android:name="rotationGroup"
         android:pivotX="12"
         android:pivotY="12"
         android:rotation="90" >
    <path
          android:fillColor="#FF000000"
          android:pathData="M8,5v14l11,-7z"/>
  </group>
</vector>
```

Comment: Nice answer for the `rotationGroup` attribute, it rotates the vector very well

Answer (score 6):

If you want to `rotation` drawable in `xml` file then simple add `android:rotation="180"` in `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_dropdown"
    android:rotation="180"/>
```

Programatically

```
val image = findViewById(R.id.imageview)
image.rotation = 180f
```

Comment: Thank you! Took so loong to find this answer!