# Draw vertical dotted line

Tags: android

I want to draw a vertical dotted line in xml, using `shape`.

I used this example:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="line">

<size
android:height="400dp"
android:width="4dp"/>

<stroke
        android:color="#000000"
        android:dashWidth="100dp"
        android:dashGap="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Then:

```
<View android:id="@+id/vertical_line"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/dotted_line"
      android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"/>
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I tried a few things, I liked the drawable solutions and found that this worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:top="-8dp"
    android:bottom="-8dp"
    android:left="-8dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="4dp"
            android:color="#df0000"
            android:dashGap="4dp"
            android:dashWidth="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

The trick is the negative top bottom and left values as these are set outside of the object now, leaving a single dashed line.

Its used in the following view.

```
<View
android:layout_width="4dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/dash_line_vertical"
android:layerType="software" />
```

Comment: It a pleasure ^^

Comment: It worked perfectly. Although I can't understand your explanation `as these are set outside of the object now, leaving a single dashed line.`? How this is drawn vertically instead of horizontally

Comment: @sha Essentially its a rectangle and three of the sides are outside the visible portion of the view.

Comment: Nice. Can you also tell me how it's figuring out `dashWidth` is vertical rather than horizontal?

Comment: Good job! and this is some text because the good job is not long enough

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line" >

    <size
        android:height="400dp"
        android:width="4dp" />

    <stroke
        android:dashGap="10dp"
        android:dashWidth="100dp"
        android:color="#000000" />

</shape>
```

Then use like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dot_line"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <View android:id="@+id/vertical_line"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/dotted_line"
          android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"/>

Comment: I used it like this< but some how it's drawing in center of RelativeLayout and i can't undertand why(

Comment: where you want to draw it

Comment: In background of View

Comment: it is in background but in center

Comment: how to make each dot circular instead of rectangular?

Answer (score -2):

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90" >

    <shape android:shape="line" >

    <stroke
        android:color="#000000"
        android:dashWidth="100dp"
        android:dashGap="10dp"/>
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Comment: Seems like there's a bug when using rotate drawable in Android M and above as per the thread here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716798/3849039