# Rotate drawable has not effect

Tags: kotlin, rotation, android-drawable

The starting point here is the need to periodically rotate a vector drawing, like for instance the hands of an analog clock.

I understand that a vectorDrawable resource does not directly support rotation attributes. I can put the drawable inside a group which can rotate the drawable, but that rotation won't be modifiable at run time.

I came across many posts explaining rotating views or canvases, as well as the rotate drawable. The latter seems to be appropriate for my purpose.

I created a new activity with the help of Android Studio 3.5 to achieve a simple rotation with the help of a rotate drawable.

**java/com.example.myapplication/MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.graphics.drawable.RotateDrawable
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val activity = this@MainActivity
        val context  = activity.applicationContext

        val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.rotation)
        val rotation = drawable as RotateDrawable

        rotation.setLevel(180)
    }
}
```

**res/layout/activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rotation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**res/drawable/rotation.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="360"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
```

I expect that the setLevel function can be used to rotate the drawable, but it has no effect. 
Changing the fromDegrees attribute in the rotation.xml does the rotation as expected. I am not sure if the maximum level for `<rotate>` should be 360 or 10000, but that is not the issue.

What am I missing? Is it a detail, or is the rotateDrawable the wrong approach altogether?

---

Related questions:

- [Rotating a drawable in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4763103)
- [Programmatically rotate drawable or view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15083811)
- [Is it possible to rotate a drawable in the xml description?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8716289)

Comment: what's wrong with `imageView2.setRotation(180)`? Or try to supply bigger value then 180. Try it with `2500`

Comment: I looked at the sources and saw this line there: `final float value = level / (float) MAX_LEVEL;`
Here `MAX_LEVEL = 10000`. So when you pass 180 it gets divided and you have rotation to `6.48` degrees

Comment: 360 vs 10000 is not the issue. I did try all kind of values.

I am doing my first baby steps with the android API and its documentation. It would still be interesting to understand why the rotate drawable doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `imageView2.setRotation(180)` instead of rotation drawable.